# Shared componentDidMount() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composition

I have several function having the exact same componentDidMount function.

Is there a way to share it ?

I'am using ES6 and apparently there is not way to use Mixin.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit in your case?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I'd rather use composition over inerithance

Answer (score 0):

finally I created a file animationCompose.js

```
const composeAnimation = {
    componentDidMount(){
        // Get the components DOM node
        var elem = React.findDOMNode(this);
        // Set the opacity of the element to 0
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            // Now set a transition on the opacity
            elem.style.transition = "opacity 250ms";
            // and set the opacity to 1
            elem.style.opacity = 1;
        });
    }
}


export default composeAnimation;
```

and then in I used es7 decorator in my Component.js

```
import mixin from 'mixim-decorator'
import composeAnimation from '../decorators/composeAnimation'

@mixin(composeAnimation)
class Component extends React.Component {
}
```